# jquery mobile Change Specific Elements

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile

So I have two listview set up and I want to differentiate between the two but I can't figure out how. I've tried to debug in Firebug but i can only change the code for all elements with that class. Example:

LIST #1

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-filter-theme='b' id='userList'>
    <li><img src='img1.jpg'/><h3>Item 1</h3><p>Details 1</p></li>
    <li><img src='img2.jpg'/><h3>Item 2</h3><p>Details 2</p></li>
    <li><img src='img3.jpg'/><h3>Item 3</h3><p>Details 3</p></li>
</ul>
```

LIST #2

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-filter-theme='b' id='mainList'>
    <li><img src='img1x.jpg'/><h3>Thing 1</h3><p>Details 1</p></li>
    <li><img src='img2x.jpg'/><h3>Thing 2</h3><p>Details 2</p></li>
    <li><img src='img3x.jpg'/><h3>Thing 3</h3><p>Details 3</p></li>
</ul>
```

In LIST #1 I need say the li elements to be:

```
.ui-li-static .ui-li{padding:0.1em 0px;}
```

.
.
.
And in LIST #2 I need the li elements to be:

```
.ui-li-static .ui-li{padding:0.7em 15px;}
```

.
.
I've tried to add the element ID in front:

```
#userList .ui-li-static .ui-li {padding:0.1em 0px;}
```

.
.
But that did not work.

Comment: When targeting an ID with a class, don't include spaces: `#ID.CLASS, #ID.class {...}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/dgt8U/

This structure **`.ui-li-static .ui-li dont`** exist, it is ether **`#userList .ui-li-static`** or **`#userList .ui-li`**

```
#userList .ui-li  {
    padding:2.1em 0px !important;
}



#mainList .ui-li  {
    padding:0.7em 15px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what about using data-theme option? That will easily differentiate your lists.

DEMO here... http://jsfiddle.net/dgt8U/2/

You can choose data-theme a to e.

## HTML

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-filter-theme='b' data-theme="b" id='userList'>
    <li><img src='img1.jpg'/><h3>Item 1</h3><p>Details 1</p></li>
    <li><img src='img2.jpg'/><h3>Item 2</h3><p>Details 2</p></li>
    <li><img src='img3.jpg'/><h3>Item 3</h3><p>Details 3</p></li>
</ul>
<ul data-role="listview" data-filter-theme='b' data-theme="c" id='mainList'>
    <li><img src='img1x.jpg'/><h3>Thing 1</h3><p>Details 1</p></li>
    <li><img src='img2x.jpg'/><h3>Thing 2</h3><p>Details 2</p></li>
    <li><img src='img3x.jpg'/><h3>Thing 3</h3><p>Details 3</p></li>
</ul>
```